# Namespace cannot directly contain members such as field or

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I get this error when I just add a class in visual studio community edition 2017 version.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CSU-app1
{
    class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Invalid identifiers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyphen is not a valid character to use as part of a namespace name. Consider the problem the compiler would have when trying to distinguish between a hyphen as part of a name like `CSU-app.Class1.PropertyName` and a minus sign.

Tips: pay attention to the line number where an error comes from - it may help *you* to diagnose the problem. And when asking a question about an error, always indicate which line the error occurred on - it may help *others* to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Funny it worked when it was a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace is a logical space i.e. It behave same as folders in localdisk C or D , such that it divides the space in drives but it does not have its own existence other than its name only , so curly brackets will show error in ur case.